Adjusting bookmark bar length of tab groups in Google Chrome, OS Windows 10
I saved tab groups in my bookmark bar, and I'm looking for how to adjust the length of the red part in the figure below.
It seems that it's not possible to change the length, maybe there is a trick to manage this case?
I'm using OS Windows 10.


What operating system? Please [edit] the tags on the question.

@DavidPostill I edited the question, thank you for the suggestion

The | icon/line looks dragable. If it's not, I'd report a bug.

@Destroy666 it's not dragable.

enable this chrome flags
and now you can pin any numbers tab group and the width will increase for that tab group automatically.
like this:
clicking on the 4 dots you can pin unmilited tabs.
clicking on the 4 dots you can pin unmilited tabs. 

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@AbidNoyon I upvoted your answer because it's a workaround

Thanks for explaining this. The screenshots helped me get there. One thing you missed. After enabling the flag, restart chrome, then you will get the 4 dots. From there, right click on the tab group to pin it in the 4-dot dropdown menu.
